# java to Access Client File System

Tags: java

I am working on a JSP project that requires system Level privileges for example I want to achieve serial Port communication without any third party API and the Methods or the Interface that Is Used For Communication Is Placed Centrally On The Server ..

Is It Possible To Achieve The Above Using JAVA only .....?

I also Know That Java Has A Sandbox Which restricts its access and A resource That could Help Is JAVA SCRIPT  .... 
Is There A Work around Or Any Suggestion That could be used TO achieve The Same Using JAva Only...

Thanks In Advance For your Time and Effort ...

Comment: You are confusing code which runs on a server (e.g. JSPs) with code that runs on a client (e.g. Applets).

Answer (score 1):

JSP is running on the server, so there is no way to access the client's file system.

If your client needs to send files to the server, you can use `<input type="file">` in HTML forms on your JSP pages.